# Tkinter Label: Retain Height when I change font to smaller size

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, tkinter, label

I have an `Label` for a quite advanced calculator app.

I'd like to be able to *change the font size when the text entered gets too long*, to be able to enter more, but retain the height of the widget just for good looks.

Here's piece of code I tried:

```
self.biglabelfont = font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 24, weight = "bold")

self.entrylabel = Label(... font = self.biglabelfont ....)
self.entrylabel.pack(side = LEFT, fill = "x", expand = True)
self.entrylabel.propagate(0)

self.biglabelfont = font.Font(family = "Arial", size = 11, weight = "bold")

self.entrylabel.config(font = self.biglabelfont)
```

But it keeps shrinking the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice to use `pack_propagate` is good, but you're doing it wrong. You must call it on the *parent* of the label widget, not on the label widget.

Here's a working example. Notice that the height of the sunken area doesn't change as the font grows and shrinks.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

BG = "white"
HEIGHT = 75
def main():
    global the_font, root

    root = tk.Tk()
    the_font = tkFont.Font(family="helvetica", size=18)

    toolbar = make_toolbar(root)
    subframe = make_subframe(root)

    toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    subframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")

    root.geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()

def make_subframe(parent):
    frame = tk.Frame(parent, height=HEIGHT, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken", background=BG)
    frame.pack_propagate(False)

    label = tk.Label(frame, font=the_font, text="0123455.67890", background=BG)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    return frame

def font_plus():
    size = the_font.cget("size")
    size += 2
    the_font.configure(size=size)

def font_minus():
    size = the_font.cget("size")
    size -= 2
    the_font.configure(size=size)

def make_toolbar(parent):
    toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
    grow = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Bigger", command=font_plus)
    shrink = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Smaller", command=font_minus)
    grow.pack(side="left")
    shrink.pack(side="left")

    return toolbar

main()
```

Comment: None of the above worked unfortuantely, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have found a 99% solution though. pady its not pixel precise, but works well, but I'm open to other solutions. When I use pack propagate on the frame and change the font it shrinks completelyand is about 1 pixel wide.

Comment: Also by grid I think you meant the rowconfigure, where the first parameter is minimum size, but its ignored for whatever reason. Please show me an actual implementation of your idea. I'm quite begginer

Comment: Do I call the rowconfigure on parent or the label ?

Comment: @JozefMéry: I've added an example using `pack`.

Comment: I see your program works. I failed to make mine work. Could you look at my program ? I'lll try to make it so you can easily find where to look since my source code 600 lines and has aditional stuff as pyperclip for clipboard operations. Thanks

Comment: @JozefMéry: no, I can't review your 600 line program.

Comment: I made comments and show where to go exactly. The problem is in the beggining and the rest is not interesting. You need to look at a few lines and see the code in action.

Comment: Well I just made a solution.. insted of fill x i do fill both it does the magic :o) Aaaaand after looking at your code you do the same. Thanks sir have a nice day, sorry for bothering